# RetrieveEntityChangesRequest for attachment

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am using CRM Dynamics 365 online,

When I am trying to use the `RetrieveEntityChangesRequest` in `C#` it works well for all entities except `attachment` and `activityMimeAttachment` (attachment that is attach to mail or other activities), in those entities I am getting the following message:

> You don't have sufficient privileges to access attachment entity

The problem is that there is no option to add privileges to that entities at all, more over I created security role with all privileges in organization level still getting the same error, but when I am trying to do the same action with system admin security role its working.

Someone has a clue?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is when it works for System Administrator role but not working for any other regular role, then you have to verify the privileges for the entity, ie **Note** in your case.

[Reference](http://www.summitgroupsoftware.com/blog/restrict-ability-to-delete-attachments-in-crm/)

I see you already mentioned about giving Org level privilege for all entities, make sure for `Note` as well.

Comment: already checked it , also note have org level privileges for all messages (create , update etc...)

Comment: @Oriel.F interesting, just another guess - do you have any team owning the record & role assignment needed?

Comment: @Oriel.F Attachment is not the same as Note. Attachment is for email attachments. I searched for particular permissions for that but couldn't find anything